# Rails exception handling using Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, error-handling, aop

I'm in need of handling exceptions in a Rails application using Aspect Oriented Programming without doing it in the conventional way.
I've found an useful toolkit named Aquarium(http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/).
I need some examples of handling exceptions using it or any other suggestions are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old example I found: http://blog.polyglotprogramming.com/2008/4/26/raising-a-different-exception-in-after-or-after_raising-advice-2 - I've not used it before, so I hope that helps.